cloneElement in client component with async server component as children not working in next.js
When using cloneElement in a client component, and the children is an async server component, this error is thrown:
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of ClientComponent.

When the server component is not async (or a client component), this just works.
Additionally, adding this line to the client component also makes this work:
if(children.$$typeof === Symbol.for('react.lazy')) { children = use(children._payload); }

Expected
Since cloneElement works for client components and non-async server components, I expected this to work async server components as well.
Provide environment information
Operating System:
Arch: x64
Version: Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0: Mon Jun 24 00:56:10 PDT 2024; root:xnu-8020.240.18.709.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Available memory (MB): 16384
Available CPU cores: 4
Binaries:
Node: 22.8.0
npm: 10.8.2
Yarn: N/A
pnpm: N/A
Relevant Packages:
next: 15.0.2-canary.11 // Latest available version is detected (15.0.2-canary.11).
eslint-config-next: N/A
react: 19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028
react-dom: 19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028
typescript: 5.3.3
Next.js Config:
output: N/A
Additional context
This might be a bug in react and not in Next.js.
In earlier versions the children was reported as  in react-dev-tools and cloneElement was working, now it is shown as { $$typeof: Symbol(react.lazy) } (when not using cloneElement to avoid the error).
